# Attach the UI tree to the screen for rendering

Tags: android

In my android app i want to attach the UI tree to the screen for rendering.

I'm not sure which method should i call for it, 
please advice.

Which method should I use ?

`setContentView()` ?

Comment: what kind of UI tree? hierarchy of Layouts?

Comment: What do the developer tutorials at developer.android.com recommend?

Comment: I still don't understand your question fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean load the layout dynamically by code? If yes then you should use:
*LayoutInflater.from(your_activity_context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, this);*
This will inflate a UI tree from your UI layout and attach the tree to your current object ('this' here, usually can be an customized UI view).
Then you can get the UI objects inside the layout:
*mImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wallpaper_item_image);*